# ASP.Core StructureMap Container

Tags: asp.net-core, structuremap

I'm very new to ASP.Core. We have a project and we must use Dependency Injection and StructureMap. I'm wondering if it is the right way to put the Container in the StartUp.cs file in the following method. And if it is `safe` to put the  `IHttpContextAccessor` in the configuration like below:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

        Container container = new Container(expr => {
            expr.For<IDataContextService>().Use<DataContextService>();
            expr.For<IHttpContextAccessor>().Use<HttpContextAccessor>();
            expr.For<ISessionService>().Use<SessionService>();
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IContainer>(container);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

when changing the base Dependency container in ASP.NET core, ConfigureServices needs to return an instance of `IServiceProvider`

Andew Lock in his blog [post](http://andrewlock.net/getting-started-with-structuremap-in-asp-net-core/) shows you how to perform that.

Taken from his blog post, it would be something like this for StructureMap

```cs
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddControllersAsServices();

    return ConfigureIoC(services);
}

public IServiceProvider ConfigureIoC(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var container = new Container();

        container.Configure(config =>
        {
            // Register stuff in container, using the StructureMap APIs...
            config.Scan(_ =>
            {
                _.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(Startup));
                _.WithDefaultConventions();
                _.AddAllTypesOf<IGamingService>();
                _.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IValidator<>));
            });

            config.For(typeof(IValidator<>)).Add(typeof(DefaultValidator<>));
            config.For(typeof(ILeaderboard<>)).Use(typeof(Leaderboard<>));
            config.For<IUnitOfWork>().Use(_ => new UnitOfWork(3)).ContainerScoped();

            //Populate the container using the service collection
            config.Populate(services);
        });

        return container.GetInstance<IServiceProvider>();

    }
}
```

If ever you're interested in using Autofac you can refer to [ASP.NET documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) on that subject